# powershell open internet explorer in kiosk mode with a terminate after 30 mins

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I would like to using powershell v1.0, open internet explorer and go to a certain web address in kiosk mode, wait 30 mins and then close all instances of internet explorer.

so far I have the following ps command which will open IE in kiosk mode and go the web address

```
Write-Host "Starting IE"
C:\Progra~1\Intern~1\iexplore.exe -k http://google.com
```

Comment: What's the question? Can you post your entire script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following your code:

```
Write-Host "Starting IE"
C:\Progra~1\Intern~1\iexplore.exe -k http://google.com
start-sleep -seconds 1800
get-process iexplore -ErrorAction silentlycontinue | stop-process -ErrorAction silentlycontinue
```